# Need help on deleting a custom font in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

Got a bit of an issue here.. Long story short, I wanted to implement the `Roboto` font into my project, but i couldnt manage to do so (failed to implement `loadAsync`). So i deleted all the references leading to `Roboto`, started up my project and this is the message i got.

- Tryed deleting node_modules and initiating npm install - didnt work
- Tryed searching for `Roboto` in the folders using search in VSCode - no leads to `Roboto` also tryed a few other things, though cant recal them now..

Would appreciate if you guys could **help me out here**, spent too many hours trying to fix this issue.

```
console.error: "fontFamily "Roboto_medium" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync."
__expoConsoleLog
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\expo\build\logs\RemoteConsole.js:80:37
error
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:59:8
error
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24
processFontFamily
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\expo-font\build\Font.js:35:16
diffProperties
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3545:38
diffProperties
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3556:8
createInstance
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:4003:29
completeWork
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14437:12
completeUnitOfWork
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17094:10
performUnitOfWork
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17304:30
workLoop
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17316:41
renderRoot
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17417:15
performWorkOnRoot
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18423:17
performWork
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18324:24
performSyncWork
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18285:14
requestWork
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18169:19
scheduleWork
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17969:16
scheduleRootUpdate
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18642:15
render
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19512:20
renderApplication
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\renderApplication.js:61:52
run
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:104:10
runApplication
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:198:26
__callFunction
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:366:47
<unknown>
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:106:26
__guard
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314:10
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    C:\Users\Jonas\desktop\galbutveiksdabar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:105:17
```

Comment: Did you try deleting node_modules and running your packager again?

Comment: yes - didnt work

Answer (score 0):

The font you're trying to load are stored in the cache for performance reasons. So most of the times I've had similar issues it was because these assets were still in the cache. You can clean the expo cache with this command:

`expo r -c`

Answer (score 0):

**Delete custom fonts in Android’s:**

```
Navigate to android/app/src/main/assets/fonts
```

remove the font(s) in the file.

**Delete custom fonts in iOS:**

```
Navigate to ios/{project-name}/info.plist
```

remove the font(s) in the file.